# AngularJS gives an error (ngRoute, DevExtreme, TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devextreme

I'm trying to let AngularJS use DevExtreme. I'm using TypeScript. Now there's a little problem, without using the DX module in my app it's all just working.. but when trying to use DX I'm getting this **error**:

> angular.js:4087Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…loudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3)

I have already been doing some research, but I just can't find any solution to this problem.

**My code for injecting the modules:**

```
var modules = ['controllers', 'services'];
modules.forEach((module) => angular.module(module, []));
modules.push("ngRoute");
modules.push("dx");
```

So, for clearance, this way it **IS** working:

```
var modules = ['controllers', 'services'];
modules.forEach((module) => angular.module(module, []));
modules.push("ngRoute");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem, some way AngularJS was not recognizing `dx`. So I went into the errors and searched and searched, and I found I had to use `ngSanitze`. So I just included the `angular-sanitize.js` file, this fixed my problem.

I also edited my `forEach` loop to this (gave some little red lines under the lambda experssion):

```
var modules = ['controllers', 'services'];
modules.forEach(
    (modules) => {
        angular.module(modules, []);
    });
modules.push("ngRoute");
modules.push("dx");
```

I hope this can help some of you as well.